# functions and operator for user define type

Tags: postgresql

I have built User Define Type with `function_in` and `function_out`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyOwnType_in(cstring)
   RETURNS MyOwnType
   AS '/home/postgres/ENCRIPTION/MyOwnType/MyOwnType.so','MyOwnType_in'
   LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyOwnType_out(MyOwnType)
   RETURNS cstring
   AS '/home/postgres/ENCRIPTION/MyOwnType/MyOwnType.so','MyOwnType_out'
   LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

As you can see each function_in receives cstring and function_out returns cstring.

The thing is function overloading and operator overriding on which I don't want to waste my time.

Is there any way to declare **DEFAULT TYPE** for my `MyOwnType` type which tells postgres that functions and operators with `MyOwnType`arguments can parse and rewrite it into `text`?

Comment: IIRC there is a special table in postgres, that defines possible type conversions and type conversion functions. It is possible to mark some of the type conversions to be done automatic.

Comment: Read this part of the manual for details. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most you can do with your type is to [mark it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) as a [string type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html#CATALOG-TYPCATEGORY-TABLE), with:

```
CREATE TYPE MyOwnType(
  INPUT = MyOwnType_in,
  OUTPUT = MyOwnType_out,
  CATEGORY = 'S'
  -- ...
);
```

> The category parameter is especially useful when adding a user-defined type to an existing built-in category, such as the numeric or string types. However, it is also possible to create new entirely-user-defined type categories. Select any ASCII character other than an upper-case letter to name such a category [...](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html)

It *may* require additional `CAST`s, as @IgorRomanchenko suggested.

Comment: I got it and read `CATEGORY` from manual but still don't understand what `CATEGORY = 'S'` is meant for?

Comment: Oops, Type category was there, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `CREATE CAST ... AS IMPLICIT` from your datatype to `text`. This way your type will be automatically cast to `text` when a function/operator requires `text`.

Details here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html